# If $X$ is a CW complex with finite dimension, $H_k(X)$ is finitely generated for all $k$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I found the following result in a document without proof:

[image]

Then I found another document with a proof that I modified to get a proof for the first document's result:
[image]

But I think this can be used to prove that $H_k(X)$ is finitely generated for $k>n$ (since $0$ is finitely generated) and for $k=n$, since $H_n(X)=\bigoplus_{c_n} \Bbb Z$ (I used $c_n$ to denote the number of $n$ cells), but not for $k<n$ (is that right?) So I tried doing this to find $H_{n-1}(X)$:

Consider the long exact sequence for $(X^n,X^{n-1})$:

$H_n(X^n, X^{n-1}) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(X^{n-1}) \longrightarrow^g H_{n-1}(X^n) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(X^n,X^{n-1})$

The first group is $\bigoplus_{c_n} \Bbb Z$. The second group is $\bigoplus_{c_{n-1}} \Bbb Z$ by (a) and the last gruoup is $0$ because $n-1 \neq n$. So, $g$ is surjective and by the first isomorphism theorem, $H_{n-1}(X)=H_{n-1} (X^n) \simeq \bigoplus_{c_{n-1}} \Bbb Z / \ker g$.

I got stuck here because I don't know that $\ker g$ is. I got the feeling that I'm taking the wrong way...

Comment: What does "dimension-wise finite" mean?

Comment: @LeeMosher It means that $X$ has only finitely many cells in each dimension.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Let $X$ be an infinite discrete space. This is a $0$-dimensional CW-complex such that $H_0(X)$ is not finitely generated.

However, your question differs from its title. What you want to prove is that if $X$ is *dimension-wise finite*, then all $H_k(X)$ are finitely generated. A dimension-wise finite CW-complex may be infinite-dimensional, but it has only finitely many cells in each dimension.

Your proof is essentially correct, but has a little gap.

You show correctly that $H_{n-1}(X^n)$ is a quotient of the free abelian group $H_{n-1}(X^{n-1})$ with $c_{n-1}$ generators which follows from (a) and (b). By the way, you do not need the first group for this conclusion. This quotient is then trivially finitely generated. See the examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_group.

The gap is that this not show immediately that $H_{n-1}(X)$ is finitely generated. To fill the gap, we observe that $H_{n-1}(X^n) = H_{n-1}(X^{n+m})$ for each $m \ge 0$. This follows by induction on $m$ by considering the exact sequence
$$H_n(X^{n+m+1}, X^{n+m}) \to H_{n-1}(X^{n+m}) \to  H_{n-1}(X^{n+m+1}) \to H_{n-1}(X^{n+m+1}, X^{n+m}) $$
in which the first and the last group vanish.

But now each element of $H_{n-1}(X)$ is the homology class $[c]$ of a singular $(n-1)$-cycle $c$. Since singular simplices are defined on a compact space, their images are compact and thus contained in some finite skeleton of $X$. We conclude that the whole cycle $c$ is contained in some $X^{n+m}$, i.e $[c]$ is in the image of $H_{n-1}(X^{n+m}) \to H_{n-1}(X)$. Since $H_{n-1}(X^n) = H_{n-1}(X^{n+m})$, we conclude that $[c]$ is in the image of $H_{n-1}(X^n) \to H_{n-1}(X)$. Thus this homomorphism is surjective and we conclude that $H_{n-1}(X)$ is finitely generated.

Although it is irrelevant here, let us observe that $H_{n-1}(X^n) \to H_{n-1}(X)$ is an *isomorphism*. In fact, if an $(n-1)$-cycle $d$ in $X^n$ bounds
an $n$-chain in $X$, this chain lies in some $X^{n+m}$ and we see that $[d] = 0$ via $H_{n-1}(X^n) = H_{n-1}(X^{n+m})$.

Comment: But in the proof they use that $X=X^n$, that means $X$ has finite dimension. If my proof is correct, can I use the same argument for $n<n-1$?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know what $g$ is or what $\ker g$ is. A $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ is finitely generated exactly when there is a surjective morphism $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n} \to M$. Then $M$ will be generated by the images of $(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$.

The idea here is quite simple: the $k$-cells of $X$ generate $H_k(X)$. There may be relations among those cells, some of those cells may be homotopic to $0$, but certainly every $k$-homology class is a sum of $k$-cells and if there are finitely many $k$-cells then it is finitely generated.

Comment: But what about $H_k(X)$ for $k<n-1$? How to prove that it's finitely generated? Why is it generated by the $k$ cells?

Comment: @Twink This is part (c) of the proof you cited. You'll notice that the statement of the theorem says nothing about the dimension of $X$. So $n$ or $k$ can be anything. I used $k$ in my answer to match the first theorem you cited but you can easily replace $k$ by $n$ and vice versa. If you agree that $H_n(X^n)$ (where now $X^n$ *is* $n$-dimensional) is generated by the spheres in $X^n/X^{n-1}$ then what you need to show (by induction) is that $H_n(X^n) = H_n(X^{n+1})$ (this is also in the proof you cited). Those spheres correspond to the $n$-cells.

Comment: So, in part (a) they're assuming that the dimension of $X$ is $n$ (so $X=X^n$) but in part (c) they're assuming that there's a space $X^{n+1}$? When they say "by induction, $H_n(X)$ is generated by at most $k$ elements", are they assuming $X$ has finite dimension? Cause that makes me think they want to say $H_n(X^n)=H_n(X^{n+1})=H_n(X^{n+2}) \cdots$ until they arrive to $H_n(X)$.

Comment: Only in part (a) are they assuming that $X$ is $n$-dimensional. I think the proof given in the second source only works if $X^{n + k} = X$ eventually. If $X$ isn't finite dimensional than I think it's still true but you need a slightly different proof.